# Issue in fetching SoundCloud Tracks using the HTTP API

Tags: soundcloud

Iam using [this link](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference) as reference to fetch tracks uploaded on my account to play them in my app.
It is clearly written in the guide that "**To access public resources you just have to pass a client_id parameter**" in the following URL

**https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID**

I have created an app on my SoundCloud account and passed the Client ID generated there in the above URL. I am getting around 50 tracks, but unfortunately none is from my PlayList/tracks.

I also tried to create multiple apps and use their Client ID, but no success.

Kindly point out if I am missing something OR should I follow some other approach.

My purpose is to fetch the tracks that are uploaded on my SoundCloud account.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The url that you provided is used to fetch details about specific track by passing additional id parameter.

To fetch tracks uploaded by specific user, you should use:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/[USER ID]/tracks?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: where should i get [USER ID]? 
The URL i provided returns me list of tracks.. not detail of a specific track.. But all these tracks are not uploaded to my account

Comment: You need to get your account ID and then replace [USER ID] with your soundcloud id. As well you can use your nickname - go to your profile and copy your nickname from adress bar and use it as user-id.
eg: http://api.soundcloud.com/users/kygo/tracks?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID